# Most appropriate model for 0-10 scale integer data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data, kruskal-wallis-test, psychology, scale-parameter

I want to estimate the effect of a grouping variable (5 groups) on an outcome variable that is an integer and a scale from 0-10. So, for the outcome only scores of 0,1,2,... etc. are possible. This dependent variable is most comparable to a Likert scale, it is not a count. It specifically is a psychological test score, were a score of 0 is a low score on a specific psychological trait and 10 is the maximum high score.

What type of model is appropriate? Would a Kruskal-Wallis be appropriate? Or is there a type of GLM that could be used? Or, since there are only 11 outcome options (0,1,2,...,10), would an ordinal regression be best?

Comment: It would help to know what the dependent variable is.  Is it a count?  Is it a Likert scale? Or what? Why is the maximum 10?

Comment: I edited the post!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With this sort of dependent variable, there are two basic alternatives: Treat the variable as continuous, or ordinal. If you decide on continuous, then a starting place is "regular" OLS regression. If you decide on ordinal, then you could start with ordinal logistic. Each might have to be modified based on whether the assumptions are met.

How to decide?

Technically, this kind of scale is ordinal. You don't *know* that the spaces between the numbers are equal. If you want to be absolutely correct, then you can't use OLS, because that does assume that the data are interval (or ratio).

But, first, an ordinal logistic would give you 10 intercepts to deal with; that's complicated. And, if the assumption of proportional odds is violated, then you might need nominal logistic, which would give you 10 parameters for each independent variable, which gets *really* hard to interpret.

Second, while it's not guaranteed that the spaces are equal, it may be justifiable to assume so. This justification would depend on the exact nature of your test.

One of my favorite statistics books is *Statistics as Principled Argument* by Robert Abelson (it's a really easy read, but will get you thinking). One of Abelson's points is that data analysis is not so much about what is *right* in some absolute sense as what you can justify.

If you argue that the scale is really continuous, will people buy that argument?

For a lot of psychological variables, it makes considerable sense.  It may be an artifact of the particular scale that yields only integers and, really, someone could be between 4 and 5 (or whatever).

You could try both ordinal logistic and OLS and compare predictions. If they are similar, then you can use the simpler and more familiar model. (How similar? That's up to you!)

Comment: I think that is insightful, Peter (+1). I am wondering what would that entail to, say, mental health scoring like [mhi-5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2265280/#:~:text=The%20MHI%2D5%20comprises%20five,standard%20linear%20transformation%20%5B5%5D) scoring (0-100). Would that be ordinal?

Comment: Thank you Peter, this is really very helpful. I can totally get behind the "what can you justify" argument, now that you have explained it so clearly. Indeed, these scales are not actually continuous, but they are most often designed in way that assumes that the spaces are approximately equal. As you can imagine, though, with only 11 response options, the distribution is far from normal (even when using conventional transformations). So I think I need a non-parametric version of an OLS in this case.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods  MHI scoring starts off 5 to 30, which is tranformed to 0 to 100. But there would be only 25 different possible scores. Still, the arguments above about too many intercepts would apply even more strongly.

Comment: @RmyjuloR OLS regression does NOT require normally distributed variables. It assumes normally distributed *errors*.  Look at the residuals.

Comment: Regular regression -- aka linear probability model -- is much used and has some articulare defenders, but a strong competitor is logit regression, treating the outcome as an approximation to a continuous proportion. This respects the bounds (here 0 and 10, easily scaled to 0 and 1) and also the variance-mean relationship (as the mean goes to 0 or 10 (0 or 1) the variance must go to zero. This model is widely available through generalized linear model software., Quasi-binomial is one term.

Comment: Even normality of errors is utopian, meaning unlikely and implausible, wth bounded outcomes. Ditto homoscedasticity. See my previous comment.